# Get current url of a webView and put it in a tweet

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, twitter, uiwebview

I'm developing an app for iOS that use the new Twitter framework.
I have a webView, how can I know the current url? And how can I use for create a Tweet?

Sorry for my bad English and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the current URL from the web view as follows: `webView.request.URL`

To allow the user to post to Twitter, you can display a `TWTweetComposeViewController` which has an `addURL:` method.  To send without user interaction you need to create a TWRequest with the relevant data (refer to Twitter's API docs for the correct HTTP requests).

Answer (score 1):

First you should read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) .
Look for the Instance method *stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:* ( - (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script )

example of use is :

```
 NSString *webViewURLString =[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href"];
```

The parameter/script 'window.location.href' is a javascript  call.

This method will give the url as a string that you can then most likely pass on to your twitter code.